# Getting error while trying to run a classic ASP website in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis, asp-classic

I have a classic ASP website deployed over IIS.
I am opening that website from the same location in visual studio 2010 (in order to debug, as per the steps mentioned [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28792/Debugging-Classic-ASP-VBScript-in-Visual-Studio-20)
The problem is that, when I hit F5 in visual studio it is giving me an error saying "your server does not support debugging of asp net or atl..."
I am able to browse the site from IIS, but I want to open it in Visual Studio in order to debug it.
What could be the possible reason and solution of this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F5 doesn't do anything good for classic ASP sites (f5 will try to compile a .NET site and then access it).

I will assume that you are trying to debug the site on the same machine where it's running. The way you debug "classic" ASP using Visual Studio.NET is by attaching to the process running the site. The easiest way to do this is to use the *Just In Time (JIT)* feature: insert a `stop` statement in the code (`debugger` in jscript) - hitting that line should initiate a server-side "Error of type "Script Debugging" was encountered. Do you want to debug?" dialog, with suggestions of available debuggers to use.

Try this and report what happens - there might be some extra steps needed to configure that machine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using IIS 7?
If so you should the server option "Enable server side debugging"... It should be in the properties window of the site, using IIS Management Console.
Once you do that, when you run the server through Visual Studio, it should open another solution on debugging mode with the relevant code.

Comment: No, I am using IIS 6. The machine is having "Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition SP 2". I have already enabled server side debugging. But of no use

Comment: OK, I had this issue with debugging on IIS 6 and I saved this link in my favourites... hopefully, it will help you. Basiccally, it tells you how to enable debug using the code itself (if something disturbs the debugging on runtime):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525253(v=vs.90).aspx